# How can I reference the inner generic type of a generic type in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Consider this generic class:

```
class TList<T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<T> {
}
```

I have another generic list class that *contains* these lists and may need to work on their members:

```
class TListList<U, T> : System.Collections.Generic.List<U> where U : TList<T>
{
   public void Foo() {
      foreach(U list in this) {
        T bar = list[0];
      }
   }
}
```

And here's a concrete implementation:

```
class FooList : TList<Foo> {}
class FooListList : TListList<FooList, Foo> {}
```

What I'd *like* to do is drop the T type parameter in the specification of `TListList` and have the compiler notice it in the `where` clause and make it available to the members of `TListList`:

```
class TListList<U> where U : TList<T> { ...same Foo() as above... }

class FooList : TList<Foo> {}
class FooListList : TListList<FooList> {}
```

Is this possible and I'm just going about it the wrong way, or is the language just not capable of this?

Comment: This is not really a language issue. Notice how you're constraining `U` to `TList<T>`. What is `T`? We don't know, because `TListList<U>` only depends on `U`, nothing is said about `T`. Therefore `T` cannot be inferred because it is not exposed as a generic type parameter in the first place.

Comment: You ought to be dropping U instead.  Is there any point in further deriving from TList<>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  Each distinct generic type must be declared ahead of time -- you can't omit `T` in the list `<U, T>`, because then `T` is an undeclared identifier.

(Also, I'm sure you know this, but inheriting from `List<>` is a very bad thing to do.  Implement `IList<>` instead, and delegate to an implementation.)